# Get height for UITableViewCell with uitextview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview, heightforrowatindexpath, sizewithfont

I found a lot of similar questions, but there was no answer for me.

I'm trying to do the same cell, like note cell in iOS contacts application. There is label on left and uitextview on the right. There is only one problem when I can't set proper cell height. When delegate first asks about cell height, I call this method:

```
 -(float)getHeight:(NSString *)descriptionFieldText
 {
  UITableViewCell * cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:@"Tmp"] autorelease];
  cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"temp string";
  [cell layoutSubviews];

  float beg = cell.contentView.frame.size.width -  cell.textLabel.frame.origin.x * 2 - cell.textLabel.frame.size.width;

  return [m_balloon.descriptionField sizeWithFont:[cell.detailTextLabel.font fontWithSize:[cell.detailTextLabel.font pointSize]] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(beg, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap].height;
}
```

But I can't get proper height on all devices and all orientations. Please help.

Comment: is there a good reason for you not subclasssing cell? and do you have `(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` in your code?

Comment: In addition to the above comment, what do you mean you can't get the proper height? Is your code not working? Is it returning nil? Does it sometimes give the wrong answer? What?

Comment: @SpaceDust Yes. And in this section I'm returning [self getHeight:string]; for section.

Comment: @Answerbot The proper height means that my textview is bigger or smaller than cell height, that was calculated in above method.